# Property [table_number] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel-9

When I do
@dd($managePublicTable)

[I have those data in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cC7b.png)

Then if I do

```
@dd($managePublicTable->table_numbers)
```

This is the query

```
$managePublicTable = ManagePublicTable::where('match_id', $id)->get();
```

then I got the error that Property [table_number] does not exist on this collection instance.
what is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

$managePublicTable variable must be inside the loop like

```
@foreact($managePublicTable as row)
@dd($row->table_numbers)
@endforeach
```

worked